# Inserting string into list before specific strings and up to a certain point

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to figure out how I would insert a specific string that incrementally increases by 1 up to a certain point. Here's what I mean:

```
my_string = ['Day1', 'RoomA', 'RoomB', 'RoomA', 'RoomB', 'Day2', 'RoomA', 'RoomB']
```

I'd like to insert 'S1' for each room that is not RoomA, increasing by 1 only once RoomA appears again in the list, and starting the count over once RoomA is followed by Day2, Day3, etc.

So the output would be:

```
my_string_formatted = ['Day1', 'S1', 'RoomA', 'S1', 'RoomB', 'S2', 'RoomA', 'S2', 'RoomB', 'Day2', 'S1', 'RoomA', 'S1', 'RoomB']
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple conditionals would do the trick.

```
my_string = ['Day1', 'RoomA', 'RoomB', 'RoomA', 'RoomB', 'Day2', 'RoomA', 'RoomB']
ans = []
for x in my_string:
    if 'Day' in x:
        # reset the counter
        counter = 0
    else:
        if 'RoomA' in x:
            # RoomA observed increase counter
            counter +=1
        ans.append(f'S{counter}')
    ans.append(x)
print(ans)
```